# Outlook 2003 won't connect to Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, exchange-2010, outlook-2003, exchange-migration

I hope you can help me with a really weird issue I'm having with one of our laptops.

Environment:

- Migrating from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010.
- Outlook 2003.
- Windows XP.

Earlier today I moved a users mailbox from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010, and ever since they have been unable to receive new emails into Outlook and the status (in the bottom right corner) says **Disconnected**. I have got her working on OWA on the new server, so her mailbox looks to be intact and not corrupted. I've also done a test and it's OK on another Outlook 2010 laptop, so all signs seem to be pointing to Outlook 2003.

The laptop is due for replacement later in the year (with new Office 2010), and I guess I can expedite that if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Tools->Email accounts. Go to More Settings for her account, then click the security tab. Make sure the "Encrypt data between Microsoft Outlook and Microsoft Exchange" is checked.

Answer (score 5):

It could be that you haven't enabled the encryption between Outlook 2003 and your Exchange Server. I just so happen to have some pre-baked instructions for our users for this kind of thing! There's also this [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2006508) if you fancy excruciating detail.

---

Open the Control Panel and load the Mail applet.

Click *Email Accounts*

[image]

*View or change existing e-mail accounts*

[image]

Select your Exchange Mailbox and click the *Change* button

[image]

Click the *More Settings* button

[image]

On the *Security* tab, make sure the *Encrypt data between Microsoft Office Outlook and Microsoft Exchange Server* option is checked.

[image]

OK out of all the screens and load up Outlook. It should think about it for a second, connect and download the new items.

---

Not that I'd particularly recommend it, but you can also remove the requirement of encryption on the Exchange Server if you so desire (note it's just the *requirement* of encryption, it doesn't disable encryption of Outlook tries to use it).

You can run the cmdlet `Set-RpcClientAccess –Server <<Server Name>> –EncryptionRequired $False` on all CAS Servers and all Mailbox Servers housing Public Folder Databases.